# Instance Failure Error SQLServer Asp Net Core

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have this connectionstring

```
"L2Connection": "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myl2db;IntegratedSecurity=True;User Id=****;Password=****;",
```

and it gives me that instance failure error...

when I debug that connectionstring it looks like

```
Data Source=.\\\\SQLEXPRESS
```

\ <- for times, I don't know why.

when I change Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; to Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; app not running there is a Json error.

any solutions?

ASP Net Core 3.1

Comment: Which type of authentication are you using, SQL Authentication or Windows Authentication?

Comment: SQL Authentication

Comment: Then you need to remove `IntegratedSecurity=True;`

Answer (score 0):

if you use password you have to remove

```
IntegratedSecurity=True;
```

otherwise your password will not be working.

And the Server name should have one slash

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=myl2db;
```

but for some reasons, I think you should try

```
Data Source=localhost;
```

Comment: but as I said, When I use one slash there is a json exception... and app crashes

Comment: You must be  not to have SqlExpress and should try local host instead

Comment: only localhost without SQLEXPRESS ?

Comment: Or just `.` if that is the default instance and you are on the same machine